# Is there something like an outward custom model binder?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I use for certain thinks custom model binders in my asp.net core project. When sending data back to the user I modify the data in the controller action and use `return Ok(data)` to send stuff back. However, my question is, is there something like a custom model outward binder? Assume this situation

You have an Endpoint, that calculates things based on a certain parameter, like

```
{
   "acceleration": "4 mm/s2", // noone does it this way, it serves only as an example
   "mass": "4 pounds",
   "force" "in kN"
}
```

Now the endpoint say does a calculation, but the calculation always needs to be performed in `m, kg and N`, so my custom model binder sees `punds, m/s etc.` and transforms the values. The calculation or whatever is done, and now comes the ugly part... If I need to send a certain value back, based on the property of the input value, it gets ugly.

So when using a transformation in the model binder, is there a elegant way to define the inverse transformation in the output?

Comment: 1. Define a custom Getter for your property. 2. Or create a action filter

Comment: That is not very practical, that introduces display logic into business intelligence

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why model binder would not influence the display logic of BI ?